# BluetoothAdapter causes activity leak

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have an activity that listens for a bluetooth headset because it plays audio. In the activity's onCreate() method, I register the listener via the adapter:

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter..getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) 
    mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(getApplicationContext(), mBluetoothProfileServiceListener,BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
```

Then in onDestroy(), I close the proxy:

```
mBluetoothAdapter.closeProfileProxy(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET, mBluetoothHeadset);
```

If I open and close the activity several times without connecting a bluetooth headset, all of the activities remain in memory. Using a memory dump, I can see that all of them are being held by a single reference from mServiceListener in android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset.

I can't find anything in the developer docs about how to remove the listener in order to release the activity. Is there any way to remove the activity as a listener so that the memory is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could possibly be better if you use Bluetooth API from your own `Service` as the `Activity` can be destroyed any time. I think this will take care of the problem, if any, because there will be only one `Service`. The service could pass messages to activities using `Handler`.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to de-register the listener, but it looks like this is the only way around it. I was able to move the bluetooth adapter and listener into a service that my activity binds to in onCreate, and then unbinds in onDestroy. This seems to have fixed the activity leak.